# How to get Default Screen Timeout Time from settings programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to get default screen timeout programmatically.

I know how to set screen timeout programmatically by using below code.

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, <Value for Timeout>);
```

But I am not able to get default screen timeout from settings.
[image]

Comment: Is that code working now as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `getInt()` for that

```
Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT))
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#getInt(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String))